# What is meant by "the times of the gentiles" in Luke 21:24?

Tags: luke

To what does Luke refer, when he records Jesus’ phrase: "the times of the gentiles" ([Luke 21:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2021%3A24&version=NASB))?

Young's Literal Translation renders the verse in question as follows:

> “and they shall fall by the mouth of the sword, and shall be led captive to all the nations, and Jerusalem shall be trodden down by nations, ***till the times of nations be fulfilled.***”

The Apostle Paul makes allusion to something called the “fullness of the Gentiles” in the following passage.

> [**Rom 11:25-27**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rom%2011%3A25-27&version=NASB) (NASB)
>   <sup>25</sup> For I do not want you, brethren, to be uninformed of this mystery—so that you will not be wise in your own estimation—that a partial hardening has happened to Israel until ***the fullness of the Gentiles*** has come in; <sup>26</sup> and so all Israel will be saved; just as it is written,
>
> ```
>  “The Deliverer will come from Zion,   
>   He will remove ungodliness from Jacob.”   
>   27 “This is My covenant with them,   
>   When I take away their sins.”
> ```

But are the two expressions related?  My understanding is that “the times of the Gentiles” has to do with the fall of Jerusalem in AD 70 (Luke 21:20) as a precursor of a future time of tribulation (Rev 19:19).

But is that a reasonable or legitimate interpretation?

Comment: Your own interpretation you are asking to validate isn't clear to me. I understand the verse as meaning the Jews are taken into captivity in 70/120 AD and that Jerusalem is never rebuilt from that point forward (i.e. no temple) until the end of time basically. I'm not sure if that's the same as your theory or not.

Comment: @Richard I have difficulty with your question: 1) Are you merely asking for exegesis on "Times of the Gentiles"? That would be a good question. 2) Are you asking if the interpretation of "Times of the Gentiles" supports a Futurist/Dispensational hermeneutic? That would also be a good question, providing you cited your source for (1). Are you attempting to extrapolate a different meaning than what you quoted? You could address it by "answering your question" or ask a question stating your meaning(with support).

Comment: Hi Richard, I think the question needs just a bit more clarification as we aren't sure whet you intent is (see discussion in The Library starting [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16794906#16794906)

Answer (score 5):

## The Idea in Brief

The "Times of the Gentiles" is the period of time when the visible theocratic kingdom on earth is absent. That is, when the visible theocratic kingdom on earth existed, the Biblical referent of time was in reference to what Jewish ruler(s) were in power. When the theocratic kingdom on earth ended with the departure of the glory of the Lord (right before the Babylonian Captivity), the Hebrew Bible then referenced Gentile powers as the referent of time from that point forward. This Gentile rulership began at the time of the Babylonian Captivity, and continues to this day, and therefore the fulfillment of the Times of the Gentiles awaits a future day, when the visible theocratic kingdom will be established again on earth.

## Discussion

In the Hebrew Bible, the theocratic kingdom on earth began at Sinai, when the glory of Yahweh dwelt in the Tabernacle (glory-dwelled = "shekinah") and later in Solomon's Temple. First Moses, the judges, and then the Jewish kings were the divinely-anointed representatives of the leadership of this theocratic kingdom on earth. Before Sinai, God's covenants with man (e.g., Noahic and Abrahamic) the divine revelation was direct and personal; at the Covenant at Sinai, however, was the first formal establishment of the Government of God (theocratic kingdom), through which the nations of the earth would be blessed.

Therefore the referents of time for the theocratic kingdom were not based on the age of the world, but based on the reigns of these respective Jewish leaders at the time. For example, Hebrew Scripture references the reigns of the Jewish kings as time-referents, since they had represented the leadership of the theocratic kingdom (even when divided).

> [**1 Kings 16:23**](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2016:23&version=NASB) (NASB)
>   <sup>23</sup> In the thirty-first year of Asa king of Judah, Omri became king over Israel and reigned twelve years; he reigned six years at Tirzah.

The rule of Jewish kings was the basis of gauging time, since their rulership was the executive authority of Yahweh, who was the Head of State of the theocratic kingdom, even if divided. The laws of this kingdom came from the Torah.

However, when the Babylonian Captivity occurred, the glory of Yahweh had departed the Temple and this theocratic kingdom on earth ended: thus the reign of Jewish kings had terminated (and so there was no longer any more referent of time based on the reign of any Jewish kings). At this time the prophet Daniel introduced the images of reigning Gentile powers on earth as rapacious animals, whose power on the earth would one day end. So post-exilic Hebrew Scripture such as Zechariah and Haggai reference the reigns of these Gentile powers (and not Jewish kings) as the time-referents, and so these -- thus "the Times of the Gentiles." The following graph provides an overview of "the Times of the Gentiles."

[image]

The last eight chapters of Ezekiel (approximately 20% of the book) concerns dozens of measurements, which suggest the literal establishment of the new temple, where the glory of Yahweh will one day dwell. (The dozens of references to precise measurements with a ruling measuring rod suggest that this temple is literal.) It was in this context of the apocalyptic end that Jesus was alluding in [Luke 21:24](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2021%3A24%20&version=NASB) to the fulfillment or completion of the "Times of the Gentiles," when Gentile rule would end in the world in general and over the Promised Land in particular. That is, Jesus was alluding to the time when these rapacious Gentile powers would no longer dominate the earth.

At the current time (today) we are living in the invisible kingdom of God (under the New Covenant), where the temple is the body of the believer in the individual and collective sense. That is, the believer operates in the kingdom of God while on earth (please see [Acts 26:16-18](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%2026%3A16-18%20&version=NASB) and [Col 1:13](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians%201:13&version=NASB)). Since this kingdom is invisible, there is no exercise of direct theocratic authority on earth. That is, there is no direct exercise of the Torah within this invisible kingdom. The beginning of this invisible kingdom was the inauguration of the New Covenant at Pentecost.

On the same day that the New Covenant was given at Pentecost was the same day that the Old Covenant was given at Sinai. Also, the same dates that the Jews escaped Egypt (and when the Egyptian Army was destroyed) are the same dates as the crucifixion and resurrection of Jesus Christ. In other word, the Old Covenant and New Covenant, respectively, were announced publicly to Israel on the same dates on the Jewish calendar in precise coincidence. The only twist for the New Covenant was the revelation of the "Mystery" later revealed to the Apostle Paul, who declared that Jews and Gentiles are now one in the mystical Body of Christ ([Eph 3:4-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Eph%203%3A4-12&version=NASB;SBLGNT)). This twist of the New Covenant was not part of the Hebrew Scriptures, and the Apostle Paul relates that when the Mystery is over, then Israel will once again become the locus of history for the return of the visible theocratic kingdom on earth.

> **[Rom 11:25-27](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rom%2011%3A25-27&version=NASB)** (NASB)
>   <sup>25</sup> For I do not want you, brethren, to be uninformed of this mystery—so that you will not be wise in your own estimation—that a partial hardening has happened to Israel until ***the fullness of the Gentiles*** has come in; <sup>26</sup> and so all Israel will be saved; just as it is written,
>
> ```
>  “The Deliverer will come from Zion,   
>   He will remove ungodliness from Jacob.”   
>   27 “This is My covenant with them,   
>   When I take away their sins.”
> ```

This Mystery is an intercalation, or heretofore undisclosed interruption, to the divine time table. When Jesus prophesied the destruction of Israel by the Romans in Mark 13, Matthew 24, and Luke 21, the destruction of indeed occurred in AD 70. However, the Second Advent of Jesus Christ did not occur immediately after AD 70 as was expected, because the intercalation of the Mystery (as revealed to the Apostle Paul) had begun after Pentecost when the Gentile Roman Centurion and his Gentile family spontaneously received the Holy Spirit without any intercession or laying of hands by Peter ([Acts 10:1-48](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2010%3A1-48&version=NASB;SBLGNT)). The baptism of the Gentiles (Cornelius and his family and cohort) shook the Jewish Christians who alone were the recipients of the national announcement of the New Covenant at Pentecost.

When the intercalary period of the Mystery is over (the rapture discussed by the Apostle Paul in [2 Thess 2:1-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20thess%202%3A1-16&version=NASB;SBLGNT)), is when God will reestablish the visible theocratic kingdom on earth again. (The literal temple described in the last 20% of the Book of Ezekiel will be the locus of the visible Kingdom on earth.) The reader must note that the Christians in Thessalonica were not Jews, but Greeks living in Greece, and so when they feared the Day of the Lord had already started ([2 Thess 2:1-2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20thess%202%3A1-2&version=NASB;SBLGNT)), they were not scared for themselves that the Romans were going to overrun Palestine anytime soon, but that the consummation of the Mystery had begun, and that the worldwide judgment of God (as later described in the Revelation of John) had already begun and they (the Thessalonian believers) were somehow "left behind."

So the "Times of the Gentiles" refers to the indefinite intercalary period of time on earth, which will one day end when the Lord comes back to earth to reestablish his rule and authority on the earth, when "the nations will be broken with a rod of iron and shattered like earthenware" ([Ps 2:9](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ps%202%3A9&version=NASB) with [Rev 2:26-27](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%202%3A26-27&version=NASB), [Rev 12:5](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rev%2012%3A5&version=NASB), and [Rev 19:15](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rev%2019%3A15&version=NASB)). This havoc before the establishment of the visible kingdom will be the ultimate fulfillment of the words spoken by Jesus in Mark 13, Matt 24, and Luke 21 (and the words written by the Apostle John in the Book of Revelation, which was written *after* the fall of Jerusalem in AD 70).

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, Scripture points to the literal establishment of the theocratic kingdom on earth at some point in the future, which will be centered on the Temple described by Ezekiel (and which translates into the eternal Zionic Jerusalem described in [Revelation 21:10-27](http://legacy.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2021%3A10-27&version=NASB), where the measuring rod appears again suggesting literal events and objects). And so, we can infer that the "Times of the Gentiles" is the period of time when the visible theocratic kingdom on earth is absent.

Answer (score 5):

**"THE TIMES OF THE GENTILES" - TO WHAT DOES THIS REFER?** (Luke 21:24)

**THE PHRASE IN CONTEXT:**

“The times of the gentiles” is one of those phrases that is all too often lifted out of its context and invested with a meaning much wider than that originally intended.

The phrase itself sits within the specific context of Jesus’ Olivet prophecy, which all three synoptists record (Mark 13, Matthew 24, Luke 21).  Luke alone gives us the phrase “the times of the gentiles” (the Greek word ethnos being rendered “nations” elsewhere in the same chapter and even in the same verse):

> “And they [the inhabitants of Judea v.21] shall fall by the edge of the sword, and shall be led away captive into all nations: and Jerusalem shall be trodden down of the Gentiles, until the times of the Gentiles be fulfilled” (Luke 21:24).

Matthew’s account regards this same event as a time of **"...great tribulation, such as was not since the beginning of the world to this time, no, nor ever shall be"** (Matt 24:21) and that, for the elect’s sake, this period of tribulation would be shortened (v.22), indicating that a relatively brief timeframe is in view.  That this period of “tribulation” refers to something which the generation of Jesus’ own day would, themselves, experience is made clear from the damning statements made by Jesus, which Matthew records for us in the previous chapter (Matt 23:33-38).

**A LITERAL TRANSLATION:**

Robert Young’s literal version, transliterates the Greek ethnos as ‘nations’ which is consistent with its rendering elsewhere in the same passage:

> “…and they shall fall by the mouth of the sword, and shall be led captive to all the nations, and Jerusalem shall be trodden down by nations, till the times of nations be fulfilled” (Luke 21:24 Young’s Literal Translation).

Although not a literal translation, the God’s Word version, using the CNE (Closest Natural Equivalent) method of translation, correctly, in my opinion, communicates the meaning of this passage as follows:

> “Swords will cut them down, and they will be carried off into all nations as prisoners. Nations will trample Jerusalem until the times allowed for the nations [to do this] are over” (Luke 21:24 God’s Word Translation).

**JERUSALEM'S IMMINENT FALL:**

Some, like many premillennialists (I am a ‘perennialist’ Isa 9:7) may argue that the phrase ‘times of the gentiles’ refers to a period of history, lasting many centuries, during which there has been no ‘theocratic kingdom on earth’.  However, I find no justification for this view in the context of Luke's account of the Olivet prophecy (i.e. the imminent fall of the city of Jerusalem and its temple).  Also, there were ruling empires in the world before there was ever a nation Israel.  Does that mean there were ‘gentile times’ long before there were ‘times of the gentiles’?  This idea doesn’t appear to be well founded and seems so out of context with the whole theme of Mark 13, Matthew 24, Luke 21.  The prophecy isn’t about non-Israelite nations being dominant or of a "theocratic kingdom" ceasing to exist, but, specifically, about Jerusalem being ‘trodden down’ by a foreign army or armies.  This is clearly the context of the passage.

**A TIME OF TRIBULATION:**

The period during which the city of Jerusalem was overrun and destroyed along with its temple, was about three and a half years (similar it would appear to the timeframe referred to in the apocalypse (Rev 12:6; 11:2) with its symbolic reference to a future time of tribulation (“a time, times and half a time”) and with reference to a very different ‘temple’ and ‘holy city’ (as John clearly regards the then and present, physical city of Jerusalem as anything but holy (Rev 11:8).

Comment: Ruminator - yes, I'll certainly do that.

Comment: Jerusalem is the holy city not because it is sinless but because God has consecrated Jerusalem as his everlasting home and the home of his People, the Jews for ever.

Comment: The Jewish leadership rejected their messiah by God's design to provide an opportunity for the gentiles: Romans 11:25 I do not want you to be ignorant of this mystery, brothers and sisters, so that you may not be conceited: Israel has experienced a hardening in part until the full number of the Gentiles has come in, 26 and in this way all Israel will be saved. As it is written:
“The deliverer will come from Zion;
he will turn godlessness away from Jacob.
27And this is my covenant with them
when I take away their sins.”  The new covenant was made between God and his people, the Jews, only.

Comment: Isaiah 62 is still to be fulfilled:  

NIV Isaiah 62:11The Lord has made proclamation
to the ends of the earth:
“Say to Daughter Zion,
‘See, your Savior comes!
See, his reward is with him,
and his recompense accompanies him.’ ”
12They will be called the Holy People,
the Redeemed of the Lord;
and you will be called Sought After,
the City No Longer Deserted.

God has an everlasting plan for Israel and the faithful remnant of the Jews. Jesus will reign for ever over Israel (under the God of the whole earth).

Comment: Also, the new covenant is not made willy-nilly with individuals but is a new covenant with Israel as a whole:

Jeremiah 31:34

**No longer will they teach their neighbor,
or say to one another, ‘Know the Lord,’
because they will all know me,
from the least of them to the greatest,”**
declares the Lord.
“For I will forgive their wickedness
and will remember their sins no more.”

Answer (score 1):

**Two Different Topics** The "Times of the Gentiles" and the "Fulness of the Gentiles" are two different topics listed in two very different books dealing with two diverse ideas.  The hermeneutical context of the "Times " deals with the invasion of the Roman Legions in a prophecy Jesus gave about the Destruction of the Temple (Matthew 24:1-3).  The chronology of the "Times" was given by Daniel in chapter 12 (three and a half years).

**Gentiles** The use of the word "Gentiles" in the plural form referred to the Legions of the Roman army because the were comprised of mercenaries from the many nations the Romans had conquered over the years. This emphasizes a "trampling down by a conquering armed force"...NOT the occupation by various nations over the centuries. And these **Times** were designated in the prophecies of Daniel 7, and 12 (a period of *time, times, and half a time*, that is 3 and 1/2 years. This was exactly the "time" the Roman generals stompted all over Judea, destroying village after village, then finally wiping out the Temple at Jerusalem!

**Fulness** However, the "Fulness" mentioned in Paul's letter is a reference to the propagation of the Gospel to the nations.  The whole chapter has been dealing with the topic of redemption (salvation) of the Jews, on the one hand, and the Gentiles, on the other hand.  An important topic, but one very different to Matthew's writing.

The prophecies of Jesus were to have *immanent fulfilment* (that generation), and Paul's sermon was to have *ultimate impact* as long as the Gospel is preached. (so in this manner, all will be saved: by faith!)

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The “times of the nations (gentiles)”  is the time (42 months, 1260 days) that the nations of the outside world rule and speak evil of us and blaspheme His Holy Name.  They..the outside nations that do not know God... are made the head while we who profess to know God are made the tail in this world. They look down upon us and mock as the 42 youths did with Elisha.

We are now living in these times.    The “fullness of the gentiles/nations” = the “times of the nations” which will be fulfilled in due season.   They shall fall by the “edge”…or the **mouth**…of the sword as the nations speak evil of us.    We fall as the outside nations are given rule over us and belittle us and tread down all of the holy things.

> Luke 21:24 KJV (24)  *And they shall fall by the edge of the sword, and
>   shall be led away captive into all nations: and Jerusalem shall be
>   trodden down of the Gentiles, **until the times of the Gentiles be
>   fulfilled**.*

We are hated of all nations for His name’s (the name of Jesus) sake during this present time (42 months) of the nations.

> Matthew 24:8-9 KJV (8)  *All these are the beginning of sorrows. (9) 
>   Then shall they deliver you up to be afflicted, and shall kill you:
>   and **ye shall be hated of all nations for my name's sake**.*

Why?

Because many false prophets have come forth in this world and are preaching “another Jesus” who all claim that they are preaching the true Jesus who is called the Christ (“I am the Christ”)….and many of His people are following those false prophets and their handwritings of church dogmas of those that enrich themselves.  Yet, their "Jesus" that they preach is not the true Christ but is the "instead-of" Christ.

> Matthew 24:3-5 KJV (3)  *And as he sat upon the mount of Olives, the
>   disciples came unto him privately, saying, Tell us, when shall these
>   things be? and what shall be the sign of thy coming, and of the end of
>   the world? (4)  And Jesus answered and said unto them, **Take heed that
>   no man deceive you. (5)  For many shall come in my name, saying, I am
>   Christ; and shall deceive many**.*

His people are being made merchandise of by false prophets….and the world sees the covetousness and blasphemes...speaking against God and His Holy Name.

When we sit together with them in their churches where this is being done, we are participating in the contempt shown towards God that the world shows.

We may be honoring God within our churches but we are also dishonoring Him by how the world judges us as they see covetousness within the churches of men. We cannot sit at the table of the Lord and also the table of devils. We are participating in the world's blaspheming as we are causing it by preaching things for money's sake.

And so the outside nations of this world are made the head and we are made the tail as a result.

During this time when many are worshipping  “another Jesus” the instead-of Christ (the “antichrist”) that the covetous false prophets are preaching (who are acting in behalf of),  the nations of this world blaspheme His Name as a result.

The “Jesus” that the deceived do now  worship is a wild beast and not the Lamb who was slain. Their preaching of "another Jesus" causes war among us who believe in God. We fight and war with one another in the divisions/denominations of men.

> Revelation 13:4-9 KJV (4)  *And they worshipped the dragon which gave
>   power unto the beast: and they worshipped the beast, saying, Who is
>   like unto the beast? who is able to make war with him?*

The “mouth” that was given to “another Jesus” (the 1st beast)  who is the “antichrist” ( the instead-of the true Christ)is collectively the mouth of all the nations which hate us for His name’s sake as they blaspheme against God and His Holy name and His tabernacle and them that dwell in Heaven.   They do this as a result of the many deceived who are worshipping “another Jesus” the “antichrist”.

Power was given unto him to continue 42 months.

If they were worshipping the true Jesus the true Christ, they would not be hated by all nations  but would be but spoken well of (called a "house of prayer") and would be glorifying God through us.

> (5)  ***And there was given unto him a mouth speaking great things and
>   blasphemies; and power was given unto him to continue forty and two
>   months. (6)  And he opened his mouth in blasphemy against God, to
>   blaspheme his name, and his tabernacle, and them that dwell in heaven***.

Power was given him over all nations as all nations see the hypocrisy and blaspheme His Name.  They are using their tongues to blaspheme against God.

> (7)  *And it was given unto him to make war with the saints, and to
>   overcome them: **and power was given him over all kindreds, and tongues,
>   and nations.** (8)  And all that dwell upon the earth shall worship him,
>   whose names are not written in the book of life of the Lamb slain from
>   the foundation of the world. (9)  If any man have an ear, let him
>   hear.*

His Holy Name is being blasphemed by all nations because of His people being deceived by false prophets who make merchandise of those they lead astray.

Those that rule (the false prophets) over the churches of men wail thus “saith the LORD” when He did not speak to them and so the outside nations speak evil of His Name because of the false prophets’ hypocrisy.

> Isaiah 52:5 KJV (5)  *Now therefore, what have I here, saith the LORD,
>   that my people is taken away for nought? they that rule over them make
>   them to howl, saith the LORD; **and my name continually every day is
>   blasphemed.***

They steal and “commit sacrilege”….that is, they are temple robbers….

> Romans 2:21-24 KJV (21)  *Thou therefore which teachest another,
>   teachest thou not thyself? thou that preachest a man should not steal,
>   dost thou steal? (22)  Thou that sayest a man should not commit
>   adultery, dost thou commit adultery? **thou that abhorrest idols, dost
>   thou commit sacrilege?***

….and so the name of God is being blasphemed among the nations of the world through them...the temple robbers.

We must not sit together with them or we are participating in the nations who are dishonoring God (even though we honor God).

> (23)  *Thou that makest thy boast of the law, through breaking the law
>   dishonourest thou God? (24)  **For the name of God is blasphemed among
>   the Gentiles through you, as it is written.***

The moneychangers are now in the temple exchanging the glory of God that is due Him from all nations for money’s sake.  The outside nations see this and dishonor God as a result.

> Mark 11:15-17 KJV (15)  *And they come to Jerusalem: and Jesus went
>   into the temple, and began to cast out them that sold and bought in
>   the temple, and overthrew the tables of the moneychangers, and the
>   seats of them that sold doves;*

And so no man can carry any “vessel” (the mortal body) through the temple as all in them are perishing away from this earth.

> (16)  *And would not suffer that any man should carry any vessel
>   through the temple.*

His house should be called of ALL NATIONS the ”house of prayer” as they are supposed to see us and praise God.  We are to be to the praise of His glory.

But, instead, they find His house being made a “den of thieves” and speak evil…dishonoring God.

> (17)  *And he taught, saying unto them, Is it not written, My house
>   shall be **called of all nations the house of prayer?** but ye have made
>   it a den of thieves.*

The Way of Truth is being evil spoken of by the outside nations because of the "pernicious ways" of the false, covetous teachers who through covetousness make merchandise of those they are deceiving. Their judgment is not sleeping as they are all perishing off this earth as well as those who are sitting together with them.  The eternal life of Jesus is not being made manifest in their mortal flesh (no flesh is being saved) when we sit with them.

> 2 Peter 2:1-3 KJV (1)  *But there were false prophets also among the
>   people, even as there shall be false teachers among you, who privily
>   shall bring in damnable heresies, even denying the Lord that bought
>   them, and bring upon themselves swift destruction. (2)  **And many shall
>   follow their pernicious ways; by reason of whom the way of truth shall
>   be evil spoken of. (3)  And through covetousness shall they with
>   feigned words make merchandise of you**: whose judgment now of a long
>   time lingereth not, and their damnation slumbereth not.*

Covetousness = idolatry.

> 1 Corinthians 10:19-22 KJV (19)  **What say I then? that the idol is any
>   thing, or that which is offered in sacrifice to idols is any thing?**

The nations of the world speak evil because of the covetousness they see inside the churches of men who are exchanging the glory that is due God from all nations for money’s sake.  The nations’ words that dishonor God is the “sacrifice to devils” and not to God.

> (20)  *But I say, that the things which the Gentiles sacrifice, **they
>   sacrifice to devils, and not to God: and I would not that ye should
>   have fellowship with devils**.*

We must not have fellowship with those who are called “brothers” but are covetous as this brings the dishonoring of God among the outside nations.  We cannot be partakers of the Lord’s table and of the table of devils.  Even though we honor God in our gatherings, they see the covetousness within our gatherings and speak against God...not glorifying Him as they should.   We are participating with them as we are causing it.

> (21)  ***Ye cannot drink the cup of the Lord, and the cup of devils: ye
>   cannot be partakers of the Lord's table, and of the table of devils.***
>   (22)  Do we provoke the Lord to jealousy? are we stronger than he?

We are to possess our “vessel”….the mortal body…in sanctification and honor by not sitting together (which is the “fornication”) with those who are called “brothers” but are covetous.

If we are sitting together (the “fornication”) in the churches of men where they are covetous…..where they are exchanging the glory of God for money’s sake…we mortally perish away with them in their destruction without manifesting the eternal life of Jesus as He does not permit any “vessel” to be carried through the temple.

> 1 Thessalonians 4:3-8 KJV (3)  *For this is the will of God, even your
>   sanctification, that ye should abstain from fornication: (4)  T**hat
>   every one of you should know how to possess his vessel in
>   sanctification and honour; (5)  Not in the lust of concupiscence, even
>   as the Gentiles which know not God**:*

We are not to defraud our brothers in any matter.

> (6)  *T**hat no man go beyond and defraud his brother in any matter:
>   because that the Lord is the avenger of all such, as we also have
>   forewarned you and testified**. (7)  For God hath not called us unto
>   uncleanness, but unto holiness.*

God gave us His Holy Spirit.

> (8)  **He therefore that despiseth, despiseth not man, but God, who hath
>   also given unto us his holy Spirit.**

Our mortal bodies are the temple of God and the Spirit of God dwells in us.  If any man defile the temple of God, him shall God destroy.  We must not join the covetous gatherings ("churches") of men (the den of thieves)which causes the outside nations to speak evil.

> 1 Corinthians 3:16-17 KJV (16)  *Know ye not that ye are the temple of
>   God, and that the Spirit of God dwelleth in you? (17)  **If any man
>   defile the temple of God, him shall God destroy; for the temple of God
>   is holy, which temple ye are**.*

We must not sit together ( which equals the “fornication” we are to flee) in the churches of men who are preaching things for money’s sake and causing the nations to blaspheme His Holy Name as a result of what they are seeing. We become one in our mortal flesh with them and are being destroyed along with their common end in this earth.

> 1 Corinthians 6:15-20 KJV   **Know ye not that your bodies are the
>   members of Christ? shall I then take the members of Christ, and make
>   them the members of an harlot? God forbid. (16)  What? know ye not
>   that he which is joined to an harlot is one body? for two, saith he,
>   shall be one flesh. (17)  But he that is joined unto the Lord is one
>   spirit**.*

Flee “fornication”….being joined together with those who are exchanging the glory of God that is due Him from all nations in order to get money.

When we sit together with them, we sin against our own mortal body as we are perishing away with them in their mortal destruction as the Lord does not permit any “vessel” to be carried through the temple.

> (18)  *Flee fornication. Every sin that a man doeth is without the
>   body; but he that committeth fornication sinneth against his own body.
>   (19)  **What? know ye not that your body is the temple of the Holy Ghost
>   which is in you, which ye have of God,** and ye are not your own?*

We glorify God by not sitting together with them who are causing the outside nations to blaspheme.

> (20)  ***For ye are bought with a price: therefore glorify God in your
>   body, and in your spirit, which are God's.***

We must not defraud our brothers in the churches.  Lev 19: You shall not steal…neither deal falsely…neither lie to one another.

> Leviticus 19:11-12 KJV (11)  **Ye shall not steal, neither deal falsely,
>   neither lie one to another.**

If we do, then His Name is being profaned among the gentiles/nations.

> (12)  **And ye shall not swear by my name falsely, neither shalt thou
>   profane the name of thy God: I am the LORD.**

But the “times of the gentiles/nations” will be fulfilled where His Name has and is being profaned among the nations because of the temple robbers they see.

The Lord will open up the Scriptures  (He will sprinkle clean water upon us) to our hearing ears and will renew the Holy Spirit within us as we shall put away the preaching for money’s sake and the covetous practices of those who preach to us.

> Ezekiel 36:21-26 KJV (21)  ***But I had pity for mine holy name, which
>   the house of Israel had profaned among the heathen, whither they went.***
>   (22)  Therefore say unto the house of Israel, Thus saith the Lord GOD;
>   **I do not this for your sakes, O house of Israel, but for mine holy
>   name's sake, which ye have profaned among the heathen, whither ye
>   went.** (23)  **And I will sanctify my great name, which was profaned
>   among the heathen, which ye have profaned in the midst of them; and
>   the heathen shall know that I am the LORD, saith the Lord GOD, when I
>   shall be sanctified in you before their eyes.** (24)  For I will take
>   you from among the heathen, and gather you out of all countries, and
>   will bring you into your own land. (25)  **Then will I sprinkle clean
>   water upon you, and ye shall be clean: from all your filthiness, and
>   from all your idols, will I cleanse you.** (26)  A new heart also will I
>   give you, and a new spirit will I put within you: and I will take away
>   the stony heart out of your flesh, and I will give you an heart of
>   flesh.

It is not because of our “works of righteousness” we have done (where in the outside nations blaspheme His Holy Name) but according to His mercy does He save us by the washing of regeneration and renewing of the Holy Spirit.  He shall save us because His Name is holy and should not be blasphemed among the outside nations because of our “works of righteousness.”

> Titus 3:4-7 KJV (4)  *But after that the kindness and love of God our
>   Saviour toward man appeared, (5)  **Not by works of righteousness which
>   we have done, but according to his mercy he saved us, by the washing
>   of regeneration, and renewing of the Holy Ghost; (6)  Which he shed on
>   us abundantly through Jesus Christ our Saviour**; (7)  That being
>   justified by his grace, we should be made heirs according to the hope
>   of eternal life.*

We are supposed to be the head in this world and not the tail.

We are to hear and do His commandments so that we may be the head (over all nations) and not the tail (where all nations hate us).

> Deuteronomy 28:13-14 KJV (13)  A***nd the LORD shall make thee the head,
>   and not the tail; and thou shalt be above only, and thou shalt not be
>   beneath; if that thou hearken unto the commandments of the LORD thy
>   God, which I command thee this day, to observe and to do them:** (14) 
>   And thou shalt not go aside from any of the words which I command thee
>   this day, to the right hand, or to the left, to go after other gods to
>   serve them.*

There will be no more curse when the “times of the nations” are fulfilled …when we finally listen and do His commandments.  See the curses for disobedience in Deuteronomy 28.

> Deuteronomy 28:37 KJV (37)  And thou shalt become an astonishment, a
>   proverb, and a byword, among all nations whither the LORD shall lead
>   thee.

The “fullness of the nations” is also in direct correlation to the “times of the nations”… about this time we are living in.

> Romans 11:25-27 KJV (25)  For I would not, brethren, that ye should be
>   ignorant of this mystery, lest ye should be wise in your own conceits;
>   that blindness in part is happened to Israel, **until the fulness of the
>   Gentiles be come in.** (26)  And so all Israel shall be saved: as it is
>   written, There shall come out of Sion the Deliverer, and shall turn
>   away ungodliness from Jacob: (27)  For this is my covenant unto them,
>   when I shall take away their sins.

Answer (score 0):

Revelation alludes to Daniel:

> [Dan 7:25 NASB20] [25] 'And he will speak against the Most High and wear down the saints of the Highest One, and he will intend to make alterations in times and in law; and they will be handed over to him for a time, times, and half a time.

> [Dan 12:7 NASB20] [7] And I heard the man dressed in linen, who was above the waters of the stream, as he raised his right hand and his left toward heaven, and swore by Him who lives forever that [it would be] for a time, times, and half [a] [time;] and as soon as they finish smashing the power of the holy people, all these [events] will be completed.

> [Rev 12:14 NASB20] [14] But the two wings of the great eagle were given to the woman, so that she could fly into the wilderness to her place, where she was nourished for a time, times, and half a time, away from the presence of the serpent.

The times of the gentiles refers to the 3.5 years of Daniel, part of his 70 heptads eschatology.

> time + times + half a time = 3.5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Both expression are related, but leading from different perspective. Let me requote these two verses in question;

> 24 They will fall by the sword and will be taken as prisoners to all the nations. Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles **until** *'the times of the Gentiles'* are fulfilled. (Luke 21:24 NIV)

> 25 I do not want you to be ignorant of this mystery, brothers and sisters, so that you may not be conceited: Israel has experienced a hardening in part **until** the *'full number of the Gentiles'* has come in, (Romans 11:25 NIV)

Both expression indicate an end, either the full number of the Gentiles is achieved, then the times of the Gentiles will end. When there is times of the Gentiles (nations), there is times of the Jews. The Lord first made His covenant with the Israelites, and subsequently He made a new covenant thru the crucifixion of Jesus with all nations (gentiles). Thus the first covenant refers to the times of Jews, and the new covenant refers to the times of the gentiles. Paul said, Jews and Gentiles will reconciled through Christ, in his words in the Epistle of Ephesians

> 11 Therefore, remember that formerly you who are Gentiles by birth and called “uncircumcised” by those who call themselves “the circumcision” (which is done in the body by human hands)—
>
> 12 remember that at that time you were separate from Christ, excluded from citizenship in Israel and foreigners to the covenants of the promise, without hope and without God in the world.
>
> 13 But now in Christ Jesus you who once were far away have been brought near by the blood of Christ.
>
> 14 For he himself is our peace, who has **made the two groups one** and has destroyed the barrier, the dividing wall of hostility (Ephesians 2:11-14 NIV)

It is worth noting that 'the times of the Gentiles' does not exclude the Jews, it is talking about the times that Gentiles become entitled in the new covenant. This is the times now, and it will end when Jesus returns. What is the 'full number' described in Romans 11:25? I don't think Paul intended to give an answer, for he knew **“But about that day or hour no one knows"** (Matthew 24:36 NIV)

Answer (score -1):

Let's analyze this first:

> Luke 21:28
>
> And they shall fall by the sword, and shall be led away captive into all nations.

70 ad. When the Romans invaded Jerusalem, the  Children of Israel had fought with the Romans. Some stayed in Jerusalem and fought and were slaughtered. The Romans put a (border) around Jerusalem and starved them out. That's why

> Luke 21:23
>
> Woe unto them that are given suck, in those days....

They put a "BORDER" (sound familiar) around Jerusalem (as a way to win because they couldn't defeat them head on) and people were eating their kids.
Luke 21:21 Then Let them which are in Judaea flee to the mountains.....
When the Children of Israel fled, they fled to the Atlas Mountains in Africa until they went into slavery.

> Deutoromony 28:68
>
> And the Lord shall bring you into Egypt (HOUSE OF BONDAGE/SLAVERY) again with ships, by the way I spake unto thee,  **Thou shalt see it NO MORE** again. (The Children of Israel was not to see their homeland Israel anymore): and there ye shall be sold unto your enemies for bondmen and bondwomen, (in otherwords, slaves) and no man shall buy you.

Sound familiar?

> Luke 21:20
>
> And when he shall see Jerusalem compasses with armies, then know that the desolation thereof is nigh.

But as a reference point,  you have to ask yourself, "who are the **Gentiles**"  What do the bible means, trodden down?

Look at how they are living over there. Hint: Their lifestyle.

> Revelation 2:9
>
> I know that works, and poverty,  (but thou art rich) and I know the blasphemy (lies) of them that say they are **Jews**, and are not, but are the synagogue of Satan.

Revelation 3:9 backs 2:9 up.

Comment: Can you please add some formatting to this to make it more readable? Thanks.

Comment: Some paragraphs would help and some bullet points, maybe.