# How are we to understand the meaning, not to mention the length, of the 'Times of the Gentiles', which likely began with Nebuchadnezzar?

Tags: prophecy, daniel, chronology, gentiles

The **"Times of the Gentiles"** started with the deposing of the last king of Judah, i.e. King **Zedekiah**, the last king to sit on Jehovah's *earthly* throne, which happened with the overthrow and destruction of Jerusalem and Solomon's temple in **607 BC**, by the Babylonians, led by King **Nebuchadnezzar**, which heralded the beginning of the **70 (x 360 day) years** of Babylonian captivity and which would not end until **538 BC, Dan,9:1,2**. See also **Ez, 21:25-27**. From **607 BC** and onwards, therefore, was to be the *Gentiles time*, which we know from **Dan 4:16,23** was to last for **seven periods of time.**

In **Dan, 4:10-37**, we learn of another of **Nebuchadnezzar's** dreams, where he is depicted (as we later learn from Daniel's interpretation) as a giant, heaven high tree, he being the highest human *(earthly)* ruler of that time. The tree, as depicted by the king, we then learn is cut down, with only its stump left in the ground, but which is then banded with iron and bronze and then left in the grass of the field, to be drenched with the dew of heaven, amongst the beasts of the field until **seven periods of time** pass. Initially, we learn that this said time period is to relate to the king himself, during a fit of mindless incomprehension, imposed by *Godly* intervention, and that he himself is to languish in the field, as if a beast, eating grass, for **7 full years**, at the end of which he is shown and comes to believe that *it is* Heaven *that* rules. We also learn, however, that the **seven periods of time** are to have further meaning, in that they are to last until ....*"the Most High is ruler over the realm of mankind, and bestows it on whom He wishes, and sets over it **the lowliest of men**."* **Dan,4:17.**

If, as I believe, ***the lowliest of men***, is a *cryptic* reference to **Jesus** taking over the *earthly* kingdom, as opposed to *heavenly* kingdom (which He inherited after his *ascension*), at the end of *Gentile* rule, then the further meaning, as to the **seven periods of time**, has to span more than *two* millenniums. **How long can we possibly, therefore, be truly talking about, when it comes to this "duality" of meaning??**

In **Luke 21:24**, we see a *definite* reference to the **Times of the Gentiles**, but I see this as just a reminder that the said times still have a long way to go. The trampling of Jerusalem, by *Gentile Nations* started with **Nebuchadnezzar**, and was emphasized further under **Vespasian** and in particular his general **Titus**, in the **1st Jewish/Roman War** of **66 AD thru 73 AD**, which incidentally covered a **7 year** time period, in its own totality, with **70 AD** being, of course, a very significant center point. But that's another story.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled - where in Luke 21:24 does it say the Times of the Gentiles started with Zedekiah? Isn't Jesus referring to the whole thing as a future event?

Comment: I'd suggest that you've supplied a lot of material external to Luke and are using that to shape the interpretation of the passage given as the 'starting point' of this question, which isn't good practice exegetically. Perhaps most of this content would be more suitable as an Answer to your own Question, and the rest can be stripped back to anchor on Luke 21:24 as the core text?

Comment: For the justification of this "seven times" beginning with Nebuchadnezzar - ask the Jehovah's Witnesses.  The events that Jesus describes, were in His day, still future and so cannot begin with Zedekiah.  Even the secular chronology used by them is out of date, being largely based on Ussher's work.  Zedekiah was deposed and executed in 587/6 BC.

Comment: I see nothing to link Luke 21:24 to Zedekiah.  The times of the Gentiles, also hinted at in Rev 11:2, 3 is more likely associated with 1260 days. 42 months or 3½ years.

Comment: @Dottard-The historical inaccuracy of 587/6 BC is proved by the fact that the 70 years of captivity ended in 538 BC, which no one disputes. You are right, however, that Jesus is talking about the events surrounding 70 AD, in Luke 21:24, but that doesn't mean that the times in question could not have, at least, started in 607 BC. Nevertheless, I obviously need to edit accordingly and will get to that.

Comment: @SteveTaylor-see recent edit.

Comment: @Dottard- Rev, 11:2,3 does indeed hint at the *Gentile Times*, in fact I believe the reference is to the first 3 1/2 years of the *First Jewish/Roman War*, leading up to the 70 AD center point of that war.

Comment: @OldeEnglish: *the 70 years of captivity ended in 538 BC, which no one disputes* - True; but captivity and destruction are distinct terms; see the [battle of Megiddo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Megiddo_(609_BC)), mentioned in 2 Kings 23:29-30 and 2 Chronicles 35:20-25; alternately, add 70 years to 587/6 BC to obtain the sixth year of [Darius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darius_the_Great), mentioned in Ezra 6:15.

Comment: @OldeEnglish - I think we have interected over this question previously in https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60901/why-did-daniel-interpret-the-70-years-of-babylonian-servitude-to-be-the-same-len/60909#60909  If you want to make 607 BC when Zedekiah was killed, then in Daniel lived to well over 100 years because he was taken captive 20 years earlier and lasted until the 3rd year of Cyrus.  The JW data is based on the unsubstantiated data of Ussher.  We now have astronomical records for the dates of Nebuchadnezzar.

Comment: @Dottard- Ok, I see and remember that, but from my studies Daniel was taken captive in 617 BC and was therefore not quite 100 years old by the time of Cyrus' 3rd year, having been taken into Babylon as a teenager. Nebuchadnezzar possibly, I say again possibly, reigned from 624 BC until 582 BC, astronomical records for his reign having not been substantiated, despite what you may have read. Zedekiah's reign is also in dispute, which is why one has to work backwards, 70 years, from 538 BC (not in dispute), to get to when the actual destruction of Jerusalem/temple happened and desolation started.

Comment: @Lucian-I'm not going to get into another battle with you over narrative and dates, as your exegesis, in my experience, leaves a lot to be desired. Post an answer if you must but leave my comment space alone.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but Why do you think the times of the gentiles starts with the end of Zedekiah's reign? And what has Dan4 got to do with that?

Comment: @0000-**Ez 21;25-27** is a referent to the end of **Zedekiah's** reign, and him being the last representative of God's rulership on earth, this started a new period of time of **Gentile** rule. See also my recent edit, as a result of the moderator's prompt, regarding **Dan 4**.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't look like a question - this looks like you've posted your answer as a question. So I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of [What is meant by "the times of the gentiles" in Luke 21:24?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/12828/2757)

Comment: @curiousdannii-**Excuse me!!**This is a question but it was a difficult one, which is why I gave as much information as possible for people to stand a fair chance of answering **and it was posted before the Q. you are accusing me of duplicating**. The OP of that Q.  has already admitted to me that he got the idea for his Q. after seeing mine, so if any Q. is a *duplicate*, it has to be his.

Comment: Note that you have to leave a space after the person's name for them to get a notification that you wrote a comment to them. Sorry, I linked the wrong question, I meant [this one from 7 years ago](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12828/what-is-meant-by-the-times-of-the-gentiles-in-luke-2124). You haven't written a single question in the question body, so I really think you should move this to an answer on that question.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Firstly, thank you for pointing out the spacing thing. My Q ended up being more about verses in Dan, 4, with a passing reference to Luke 21:24, so I don't think for one minute that I should be answering that Q from 7 years ago, which, incidentally, I did look to, at least at one point in my processing. I don't know what you mean by... *"you haven't written a single question in the question body"* ... Also, in my Q, I probably should have bolded, like thus: **How long can we possibly, therefore, be truly talking about, when it comes to this 'duality' of meaning??**

Comment: @curiousdannii - Oh, I see what you meant. I didn't bold and I didn't put any question marks after that sentence, so I'll do it now.

Comment: There’s a paper that I read, which was later published as a book - sorry  - that went into great and interesting detail about the way that the ancient cultures in question thought of, constructed and described the passage of time. It was much more complex and reticulated than simply turning 365 1/4 days into 360. Not very helpful, I know, but I’ll try to find it and notify you.

Comment: I will also find a very interesting theory around Daniel’s 70th week that proposes that a “great prophetic week”, beginning around the Abrahamic covenant and with Jesus’ death 3 1/2 ‘days’ later, ending with the Day of the Lord 3 1/2 days after that. It ties in nicely with the measuring of the temple vision in Rev but is lacking somewhat in exegetical substantiation (it may indeed be exegetically sound - but the links are lacking and one would need to piece the bits together oneself. The author then goes on to state how America is in Revelation, at which point he loses me!)

Comment: As dannii explained above, this Question at present imports a great deal of information that is external to the text, and so before anybody writes an answer you've already asked them to eisegete your own understanding of various other passages. I'd agree that most of the material probably belongs in your own 'Answer' to this question. Sitting down to think about writing an answer myself, I found it very distracting having to factor in all sorts of things you've pre-decided on the topic, and that makes it difficult to exegete the text.

Comment: @SteveTaylor - As it so happens, I am presently reading background material, with a view to *truly* answering my own question. The so-called **Gentile Times**, or **Appointed Times of the Nations** have intrigued me for more than 30 years. The answer, however, is pointing towards controversy, so I can't be too casual about it, but hopefully I will enlighten myself further if nothing else.

Comment: @SteveTaylor I guess we have *bewildered* silence here, apart from the anonymous and therefore cowardly downvote. When I said that my A. was pointing towards the "controversial", I maybe should have used 2 words "being astonishing", or more, "being wildly out there". I could, or should add a "PS", you tell me? In Ryrie's [NASB] study bible, his notes, on Lu, 21:7 and then 21:24, he states this: *when...will these things be?* There is a double perspective in Christ's answer-the destruction of Jerusalem in A.D. 70 and the tribulation days just prior to His second coming. Verses 8-19 and 25-28..

Comment: @SteveTaylor ... relate particularly to the latter time while vv. 20-24 refer to the former. **21:24**...*the times of the Gentiles.* The period of Gentile domination of Jerusalem, which began probably under Nebuchadnezzar, was certainly in effect in A.D. 70, and which continues into the tribulation days (cf Rev, 11:2)... Unquote. He is however, like most theologians/historians a proponent of the 587/6 B.C. destruction of Jerusalem and it's temple.

Comment: No idea who has downvoted you - wasn't me! I think the silence is evidence of my last comment - the only attempted Answer other than your own basically had to discard all the extraneous details. I'll Close it for now until you've refined the question some more, and hopefully you'll get a better range of responses afterwards.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it inserts a lot of unnecessary extraneous details that are distracting and makes it very difficult to answer the question exegetically.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the phrase "the times of the Gentiles" appears exactly once in
Luke 21:

> 20 “When you see **Jerusalem being surrounded by armies**, you will know that its desolation is near.

It began with the besieging of Jerusalem.

> 21Then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains, let those in the city get out, and let those in the country not enter the city. 22For this is the time of punishment in fulfillment of all that has been written. 23How dreadful it will be in those days for pregnant women and nursing mothers! There will be great distress in the land and wrath against this people. 24They will fall by the sword and will be taken as prisoners to all the nations. Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles until the **times of the Gentiles** are fulfilled.

This is where the "times of the Gentiles" is mentioned and defined.

> 25 “There will be signs in the sun, moon and stars. On the earth, nations will be in anguish and perplexity at the roaring and tossing of the sea. 26People will faint from terror, apprehensive of what is coming on the world, for the heavenly bodies will be shaken. 27At that time they will see the **Son of Man coming** in a cloud with power and great glory. 28When these things begin to take place, stand up and lift up your heads, because your redemption is drawing near.”

It ends with the second coming of Christ.

This was Jesus' definition of the times of the Gentiles.
There could be other definitions but not according to Jesus' words.

Comment: I actually referenced **Luke 21:24** in the 'body' section of my question and then later, in my list, referenced **Luke 21:11 and 21:26**. Although most definitely Jesus' words, with "duality" of meaning, initially prophesying as to the **1st Jewish/Roman War** of **66 AD thru 73 AD** and then with *veiled* regard to the **End Times**, but unless you have a *credible* alternative explanation for **Dan, 4:10-37** then you might as well be "whistling in the wind." Furthermore, when in **Luke 21:32**, Jesus makes ref. to "this generation", he has to be referring solely to **70 AD**.

Answer (score -1):

**How are we to understand the meaning, not to mention the length, of the "Times of the Gentiles", which likely began with Nebuchadnezzar?**

**Historical Context**

Towards the end of the second millennium, some 1200 years before the birth of **Jesus**, the Israelite nation was somewhat leaderless. The tribes of Israel each lived autonomously in their own regions. There was no central authority and the tribes were left to their own devices politically. Charismatic leaders, **seen as divinely appointed**, came and went. These leaders were known as **Judges**, including the likes of Gideon and the more relatable historical figure of **Samson**. In the absence of a judge, priests and prophets often took on the leadership role, which is where the prophet **Samuel** entered the picture, a very influential figure. Samuel, however, was not going to live forever, and faced with this prospect, as well as a **Philistine** threat, a group of elders asked Samuel to do the *previously* unthinkable: **appoint a permanent king of Israel**. Samuel, *reluctant* at first, chose a young man from the tribe of Benjamin, by the name of **Saul**, who became the first **divinely appointed** king of Israel. Saul, along with Johnathon his son, led the Israelite armies to defeat the Philistines and other traditional foes. Saul, however, eventually fell foul of his divine purpose and transgressed the divine law, profusely angering Samuel, resulting in having the mantle of kingship taken away from him by **God**, Himself. Samuel was then subsequently instructed by God to pave the way for Saul's successor, **David**, the slayer of **Goliath**, to become the second **divinely appointed** king of Israel. A number of further **divinely appointed** kings would follow David, most notably his son **Solomon**, until there were no more **divinely appointed** kings to be had.

**Times of the Gentiles, begin**

Consequently, the **Times of the Gentiles**, or, **Appointed Times of the Nations** started with the deposing of the last king of Judah. i.e. King **Zedekiah**, the last king to sit on **Jehovah's** *earthly* throne, which happened with the overthrow and destruction of Jerusalem and Solomon's temple in **607 BC**, by the Babylonians, led by King **Nebuchadnezzar**, which heralded the beginning of the **70 (x 360 day) years** of Babylonian captivity and which would not end until **538 BC, Dan, 9:1,2**. See also **Ez, 21:25-27**. From **607 BC** and onwards, therefore, was to be the ***Gentiles time***, which we know from **Dan, 4:16,23** was to last for **seven periods of time**.

**NB:-**

In **Zech, 1:12** and again in **Zech, 7:5**, we see further references to the *same* 70 years of Babylonian captivity, as referred to in **Dan, 9:1,2** and **Jer, 25:11 and 29:10**, but in Zechariah the 70 years would appear to end at the completion of the 2nd temple, in **516 BC**, which would suggest that the 70 years started in **587/6 BC**, which according to the historical record, at least, was when the destruction of Jerusalem and Solomon's temple *supposedly* took place. However, if one checks out "Biblehub Commentaries", there is some suggestion that, although the 70 years of captivity had already ended in **538 BC** (an undisputed date), it took another 20-22 years of suffering God's indignation, until the temple was completed, making for some 90 years (at least until **518 BC**) of actual desolation and then further indignation by way of God's anger. So, although *these* 70 years would seem to have ended in **518 BC** (as opposed to the actual temple completion date of **516 BC**), they really did end in **538 BC**.

**Nebuchadnezzar's Dream**

As further stated in the question body: In **Dan, 4:10-37**, we learn of another of **Nebuchadnezzar's** dreams, where he is depicted (as we later learn from Daniel's interpretation) as a giant, heaven high tree, he being the highest human *(earthly)* ruler of that time. The tree, as depicted by the king, we learn is cut down, with only it's stump left in the ground, but which is then banded with iron and bronze and then left in the grass of the field, to be drenched with the dew of heaven, amongst the beasts of the field until **seven periods of time** pass. Initially, we learn that this said time period is to relate to the king himself, during a fit of mindless incomprehension, imposed by *Godley* intervention, and that he himself is to languish in the field, as if a beast, eating grass, for **7 full years**, at the end of which he is shown and comes to believe that *it is* Heaven *that* rules. We also learn, however, that the **seven periods of time** are to have further meaning, in that they are to last until .... *"the Most High is ruler over the realm of mankind, and bestows it on whom He wishes, and sets over it **the lowliest of men.**"* **Dan, 4:17. [NASB]**

If, as I believe, ***the lowliest of men***, is a *cryptic* reference to **Jesus** taking over the *earthly* kingdom, as opposed to *heavenly* kingdom (which He inherited after his *ascension*), at the end of *Gentile* rule, then the further meaning, as to the **seven periods of time**, has to span more than *two* millenniums....**How long can we possibly, therefore, be truly talking about, when it comes to this duality of meaning??**

**Jesus Christ begins his rule**

> In Revelation chapter 12, verses 6 and 14, we learn that 1260 days are equal to "a time [that is, 1 time] and times [that is, 2 times] and half a time." That is a total of 3 1/2 times. So "a time" would be equal to 360 days. Therefore, "seven times" would be 7 times 360, or 2,520 days. Now if we count a day for a year, according to a Bible rule, the "seven times" equal *2520 years*.-Numbers 14:34; Ezekiel 4:6.
>
> We have already learned that "the appointed times of the nations" began in the year **607 B.C.E.**. So by counting 2520 years from that date, we come down to **1914 C.E.**. that is the year these "appointed times" ended.

...Taken from p.141, of the "You Can Live forever in Paradise on Earth", by the "Watch Tower Bible and Tract Society" 1982 edition.

**Conclusion**

Can we conclude in all honesty that **Jesus Christ** began to rule as king, over all the earth (in addition to his heavenly governmental role, as already stated) in **1914** ?? Well, let's think about this. If Christ has already returned to rule in his Father's kingdom, why do we not see him?

> *2) "In my Father's house are many dwelling places; if it were not so, I would have told you; for I go to prepare a place for you. 3) And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again, and receive you to myself; that where I am, there you may be also. 4) And you know the way where I am going."* **John 14:2-4 [NASB]**

**Jesus** was talking directly to his disciples, after his resurrection, while in one of his many *seemingly* fleshly forms, which he from time to time partook of (at least in the 40 days prior to his ascension) and was comforting them as to the fact that they would be joining him in his *heavenly* kingdom.

At his return (i. e. return to power), Christ does not come to live on earth. Rather, those who are to rule alongside him are taken to live with him in heaven. In fact Christ goes on to say:

> *"After a little while the world will behold me no more; but you will behold me; because I live, you shall live also."* **John 14:19 [NASB]**

So the world (those outside of those with the heavenly calling) will not *actually* see him anymore. Later on, during the *Great Commission* Paul says the following:

> *"Therefore from now on we recognize no man according to the flesh; even though we have known Christ according to the flesh, yet now we know him thus no longer."* **2 Cor, 5:16**

There are many other similar Bible verses, like the ones mentioned here in this conclusion, that speak to the fact that *no* further *physical* manifestations of Jesus Christ will present themselves to the *all seeing eye*. So, for all we truly know, Christ may well have *returned* to power, in heaven, in **1914 AD** even, and already commenced his rule over all the earth. It would have been possibly then, therefore, that the *loud* cry was heard in heaven, saying:

> *"Now the salvation, and the power, and the kingdom of our God and the authority of His Christ have come, for the accuser (Satan) of our brethren has been thrown down ..."* **Rev, 12:10 [NASB]**

In further conclusion, we can now see that **"The End of the World"** may now be at hand. If Jesus Christ threw Satan and his angels out of heaven, at the beginning of his kingdom rule, in **1914**, then have we (fleshly humans) been witness to **the Sign** of his **Presence** in these now *presumptive* last days. I would hazard a guess that we could, very well, have already been witnesses to the *sign*, that, Jesus informed his disciples of, just before his death, would be the evidence of his **Pa.rou.si.a**. Consequently, could the following have been *possibly* undergoing fulfillment since 1914:

1. **"NATION WILL RISE AGAINST NATION AND KINGDOM AGAINST KINGDOM."-Matthew 24:7**
2. **"THERE WILL BE FOOD SHORTAGES."-Matthew 24:7**
3. **"THERE WILL BE EARTHQUAKES IN ONE PLACE AFTER ANOTHER."-Matthew 24:7**
4. **"IN ONE PLACE AFTER ANOTHER PESTILENCES."-Luke 21:11**
5. **"INCREASING OF LAWLESSNESS."-Matthew 24:12**
6. **"MEN BECOME FAINT OUT OF FEAR."-Luke 21:26**
7. **"DISOBEDIENCE TO PARENTS."-2 Timothy 3:2**
8. **"LOVERS OF MONEY."-2 Timothy 3:2**
9. **"LOVERS OF PLEASURES RATHER THAN LOVERS OF GOD."-2 Timothy 3:4**
10. **"HAVING A FORM OF GODLY DEVOTION BUT PROVING FALSE TO ITS POWER."-2 Tim, 3:5**
11. **"RUINING THE EARTH."-Revelation 11:18**

**ARMAGEDDON**

As I have already pointed out that the world (fleshly humans) may not see Christ again, then how do we account for the vision of Christ on a white horse; with his eyes aflame with fire; many diadems on his head; clothed with a robe dipped in blood; with armies of angels, also on white horses, following; with a sharp sword protruding from his mouth, with which he may smite those **Nations**, aforementioned. **Rev, 19:11 thru 16**

I knew this vision of Christ was going to be the most difficult to address in this posting and I guess it's fitting that it comes at the end of this dissertation. All I can say is that the vision, while certainly John's vision, of the *spiritual* forces in heaven, led by the *spiritual* Jesus, now with many crowns, it may well not be seen the same way by us *fleshly* humans. Nevertheless, we will no doubt be acutely aware of what is transpiring, somehow or another. In any case, one can't help but wonder as to the reality of Jesus being seen with a sword protruding from his mouth. This is obviously *symbolic*. But, then that begs the obvious question: **How much more of John's vision could be symbolic?**. One can only wonder.....